# Center two divs in the middle of a wrapper

Tags: css

I have this CSS problem:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">I am div 1</div>
    <div id="right">I am div 2</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make **"I am div 1 I am div 2"** center inside the wrap div. Not sure how to explain it. The design is only in percent, liquid design and I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: *Not sure how to explain it. * Well, how about telling us if you want to center them horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;  
}

#left, #right {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;    
     padding: 2%;   
}
```

**[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/dsatp3vz/)**

This will center two div blocks within the wrap, side by side.

---

**EDIT: 2015 Flexbox Solution**

Flexbox is much more widely supported now and is most likely a better solution for this situation. There are some quirks that come along with the above inline-block method, such as horizontal spacing and vertical alignment issues. Here is the flexbox solution:

```css
#wrap {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5%; 
    width: 80%;  
}

#left, #right {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 2%;   
}
```

**[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/nb93mjaz/)**

Be sure to check [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) to confirm that flexbox is supported in the browsers you are supporting.

*2019 Edit: Commenter MC9000 brought up that my example is not responsive in percents, as the original question mentioned. I've updated my examples to show that this works with percentage based sizing just like it does with pixel based sizing.*

Comment: But what is this margin space between the two divs? I have to add `margin-right:-1px` to remove them, [image](http://screencast.com/t/RO0PQqjv)

Comment: @Mohammad Inline-block elements will respect one occurrence of white space, just like inline elements. To get rid of this gap, either use the flexbox solution I added on, remove the space in the HTML markup between the two elements, or use the HTML comment trick to remove that space. The latter can be seen in a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ymfz9hyr/

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Was very helpful :)

Comment: I was looking all over the internet but your reply was the best explained, thank you very much :)

Comment: "design is only in percent" -he requested a responsive solution, however, this solution won't work as you've defined the widths in pixels.

Comment: @MC9000 Good catch. I updated my code and demos to show that this method will work with responsive percentage based code as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align:center;` would center this for you:

```
#wrap{
  width:50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#left, #right{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DbNs6/1/