# Strange behavior when putting 2 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to put 2 divs next to each other centered, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835436/2514164). The problem is that it seems that my right div is always a bit under the left one when I put a `<span>` and a heading into the right div. Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

```css
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 160px;
  max-height: 160px;
}
#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Heading</span>
    <div id="some-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top;` on the #right and #left divs to get the wanted result

```css
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 160px;
  max-height: 160px;
}
#left {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Heading</span>
    <div id="some-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will work until another element is added; `vertical-align` attributes will need to be specified for all direct children of `#wrapper` here.

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block`elements are aligned according to the baseline of the included text. If there is no text, the bottom border will act as the baseline. In you example, the bottom border of the left DIV is aligned with the baseline of the text in the right div. If you erase the text (independently from the `span` tag), they are aligned. If there is text in both boxes, they will be aligned by their lowest text lines (see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqpJRg)

To align both boxes, use `display: block` and `float: left`on the two DIVs, and for the wrapper `position: relative;` and `margin:auto` PLUS a fixed width (the sum of both DIV widths) to center it.

Here's a codepen of the result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPOzaZ